# Parent component value is not changing by its child

Tags: angular, typescript

datepicker -https://plnkr.co/edit/4mLtl6?p=preview

```
 <datepicker [id]="'create-invoice-invoice-date'" [(value)]="duedate"></datepicker>
```

I have passed "duedate" to datepicker but in my app component ,I did not get change reflection.

Comment: Some more code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add `(change)="function(data){...}` instead of [(value)]. However you can use input type date.

If you really want your two way databinding, you should have within your datepicker component the:

```
 @Input() value: string;
```

And then the emmitter:

```
@Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

And when the value changes the emit the event.

Comment: It's more work to create a function every time, if you are writing a plugin type component.

Comment: @mukundpatel I think you are missing the emitter in your date.ts. And it should be... if input is named x, then the emiter should be named xChange

Answer (score 1):

You cant bind an output without writing event handling logic in Angular - this is because "two way binding" is implemented as one way data binding + event binding, because this avoids the substantial performance cost of *"real"* two way data binding (which was one of the performance issues with AngularJS).

It is, however, very easy to implement using `get` & `set` methods. Using your example (note that I've renamed your input parameter from *value* to *invoiceDate*), you need to add the following code. Note in particular the methods established for getting and setting `invoiceDate` - which gives us the ability to `emit()` the value of our private local var `invoiceDateValue` to any external watchers.

```
private invoiceDateValue: string = "";
@Output() invoiceDateChange = new EventEmitter();

@Input()
get invoiceDate() {
  return this.invoiceDateValue;
}

set invoiceDate(val) {
  this.invoiceDateValue = val;
  this.invoiceDateChange.emit(this.invoiceDateValue);
}
```

Here is the full plunk including the above: https://plnkr.co/edit/WBdmUp?p=preview